# Help Please Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match the configured compilers in your config*contracts/hello-world.sol ("0.8.4")

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat-deploy, npm

[image: please check it out i already add comma after the curly][image: here is the both file side by side with error returned][image: Here is the new error i get when using pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;][image: Here is the * contracts/hello-world.sol (^0.8.4) error i get when trying to compile with npx hardhat run scripts/interact.js --network ropsten]Hi Please am unable to figure out why i get this error while trying to compile my interact.js script using npx hardhat run scripts/interact.js --network ropsten
on vs code : Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config.

- contracts/hello-world.sol ("0.8.4")

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose

here's my solidity code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT


pragma solidity "0.8.4";
contract HelloWorld {
    event updatedmessages(string oldStr, string newStr);

    string public message;

    constructor (string memory initmessage) {
    message = initmessage;
    }

    function update(string memory newMessage) public {
       string memory oldMsg = message;
       message = newMessage;
       emit updatedmessages(oldMsg,newMessage);
    }
}
```

here's the hardhat.config.js

```
/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
 require('dotenv').config();
 require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
 require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");
 const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
 const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY;
 module.exports = {
   solidity: "0.8.4",
   defaultNetwork: "ropsten",
   networks: {
       hardhat: {},
       ropsten: {
          url: API_URL,
          accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
       }
   },
   etherscan: {
     // Your API key for Etherscan
     // Obtain one at https://etherscan.io/
     apiKey:ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
   }
 };
```

ANY IDEA on how to solve this error [![here's the Sol file [image: ][1][1]] Please Help Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5):

try this:

at `hartdhat.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.7.1",
};
```

`0.7.1`--> `0.8.4` (solidity version you use in the smart contract)

if not work, comment below, or git upload code and give link.

Comment: Thanks i tried it already but still returns error: Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config.

  * contracts/hello-world.sol (^0.8.4)

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose

Read about compiler configuration at https://hardhat.org/config
Any idea on how to solve this Thanks

Comment: try these: 
try 1.  "0.8.4"; --> 0.8.0 (remove brackets).

try 2:  at solidity code: pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;.

try 3: reduce solidity version on both `.sol` & `hardhat.config.js` e.g. 0.7.0 .


tell if any of these 3 methods don't work.

Comment: i go this new error after using this pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

Comment: Downloading compiler 0.7.0
Compiled 1 Solidity file successfully
/Users/user/Desktop/hello-world/contracts/hello-world.sol:4
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
       ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27) at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)

Comment: Any idea what the problem is here Please

Comment: git clone it https://github.com/aakash4dev/BHUNTXeth . Your solidity codes are compiling properly in these codes in my computer at Greeter.sol.
i will delete the project after you say : cloned. I have replaced greeter.sol codes with your codes.

Comment: Alright Thanks for the help but please how do i git clone it? Do you mean i add my code to your repository

Comment: No, just copy paste Solidity & config file.

Comment: Or if not worked, your node modules are older. Use latest version of every module. E.g. SolcJS & hardhat.

Comment: Or upload your project to GitHub, give link, i will try to remove all errors.

Comment: I have uploaded the project sol file here is the link https://github.com/Deamonk1/aakash4dev.git Please check it out if there's anything else you need  Thanks  https://github.com/Deamonk1/aakash4dev.git

Comment: i have  latest version version of every module SolcJS & hardhat on vs code

Comment: Please Have you seen the project on github link https://github.com/Deamonk1/aakash4dev

Answer (score 3):

it needs to match up with what's in module.exports in your hardhat.config.js

but the quotes in the contract are causing the problem

try this

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
```

Comment: Thanks I already changed that but it still give error

Comment: Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config.

  * contracts/hello-world.sol (^0.8.4)

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose

Read about compiler configuration at https://hardhat.org/config
Any idea please Help

Comment: Please Any idea on how to solve this i have attached a new image of the error i got

Comment: this image is showing the contract's pragma statement has the version inside quote marks instead of like this ^0.8.4

Comment: i already changed it to this pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0; but it returned a new error

Comment: Downloading compiler 0.7.0
Compiled 1 Solidity file successfully
/Users/user/Desktop/hello-world/contracts/hello-world.sol:4
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
       ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822

Comment: I added the new image Please check any idea Thanks

Comment: i wrote it already without " but still returns same errors here's my sol code:

Comment: // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT


pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;
contract HelloWorld {
    event updatedmessages(string oldStr, string newStr);

    string public message;

    constructor (string memory initmessage) {
    message = initmessage;
    }

Comment: }

    function update(string memory newMessage) public {
       string memory oldMsg = message;
       message = newMessage;
       emit updatedmessages(oldMsg,newMessage);
    }
}

Comment: sorry. I must apologise. the double quotes wasn't the problem.
could you please update with just a picture of the contract code and the hardhat config files side by side and error message below all in one pic? thx

Comment: I Already upload a new image of the file side by side Please check it out thanks

Comment: the problem has to be in your hardhat config. some small typo. 
... can you put a comma after your the curly braces that don't have them in the HH config? i.e. },

Comment: Okay can you please  help me highlights the parameter or code block that need comma  },

Comment: please check it out i already add comma after the curly also uploaded a new image of config

Comment: I'm sure at this point in time you have a problem in the the hardhat config file or file it's referencing e.g. .env. are you getting valid values from .env? you could add console.log lines for the environment variables to check you're getting the values in as expected. Have you tried it without the --network args? e.g. npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js?

Comment: Yeah my contract got deployed but when i run  npx hardhat run scripts/interact.js in order to start interaction with my contract using interact.js script i get this error                pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;
       ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18) Any idea of the lines that needs  re edit or changed . i did add console.log in env but what i'm really trying to compile and deploy is a interactive script to interact with my contract after deploying interact.js script

Comment: Hi i think i fixed it already but returned      error i have attached a new image please check it thanks any idea on what Happened                                            
    contracts/hello-world.sol:8:4: SyntaxError: No visibility specified. Did you intend to add "public"?
   constructor (string memory initmessage)  {
   ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

Error HH600: Compilation failed

Answer (score 1):

you are getting that error because your code can't find a particular version to compile your various contracts because they are of different versions. try adding this   `solidity: { compilers: [{ version: "0.8.9", }, { version: "0.6.6", }, { version: "0.6.0", settings: {}, }],`
},
to your `hardhat.config.js`. Just a note, that some compiler versions are better or would I rather say more compatible than others. so you might have to shuffle through some of them in your contract. And also try clearing your cache by running `npx hardhat clean` or `yarn`. depending on your package manager. Ypu might aslo want to check if you contract is refrencing any other contract and check the version that one is running on. Good luck.

-Cheers

Answer (score 0):

We could include multiple compilers in hardhat.config.js

Source : https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/advanced/multiple-solidity-versions#multiple-solidity-versions

```
  module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.12",

  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: "0.8.12",
      },
      {
        version: "0.8.20",
        settings: {},
      },
    ],
```